# how to override subcategory description page magento 2....?

Tags: magento2

Actually i want to move subcategory description left.Is it possible please suggest me.

below code not useful.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mage_Tempjs',
    __DIR__
);


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mage_Tempjs" setup_version="2.0.2" active="true">

    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: which them you are using default luma?

Answer (score 0):

At magento2, you can change a block position from one container area tp another using [`<move>`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html) .

If you using magento default luma theme then create `catalog_category_view.xml` at  `app/code/Mage/Tempjs/view/frontend/layout`.

add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <move element="category.description" destination="sidebar.main" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: i am facing error like this...{"0":"Element name and destination must be specified.","1":"#0 E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mage\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\View\\Layout\\Reader\\Move.php(37)

Comment: I did mistake `<move name=` should be `<move element=`.Update at answer